# "Пост дня" на сайте

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Создаю "Рецепт дня" в ruby on rails.
Нужно, чтобы случайным образом выводилась запись, и не менялась в течении одного дня.

Можно вывести случайный рецепт:

```
@recipe_day = Recipe.order("RANDOM()").first
```

Но при каждой перезагрузке страницы, естественно, он будет выводиться разный.
Как сделать, чтобы он не менялся на протяжении всего дня?

Comment: Либо добавть поле типа `boolean` в таблицу 'recipes', и выбирать первую запись со значением `true` в этом поле, либо определять "Рецепт дня" по каким-то другим параметрам, либо где-то ещё хранить `id` "Рецепта дня"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавьте поле top через миграции:

```
rails g migration AddTopToRecipes top:boolean
```

Во избежания трёх состояний (true, false, nil) лучше сделать так:

**add_top_to_recipes.rb**

```
class AddTopToRecipes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :recipes, :top, :boolean, null: false, default: false
  end
end
```

Не забудьте выполнить миграцию:

```
rake db:migrate
```

**recipe.rb**

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Return the current recipe of the day
  def self.recipe_of_the_day
    self.find_by_top(true)
  end

  # Set up the recipe of the day
  def self.setup_recipe_of_the_day
    current_recipe = self.recipe_of_the_day

    recipe_ids = self.all(
      :select => "id",
      :conditions => ['id != ?', current_recipe.id]
    )

    next_recipe = self.find(recipe_ids[rand(recipe_ids.length)])

    current_recipe.update_attribute(:top, false)
    next_recipe.update_attribute(:top, true)
  end
end
```

Для того чтобы раз в день выбирать рецепт дня используйте [whenever](http://github.com/javan/whenever).
Установите задачу по расписанию:

**schedule.rb**

```
every 1.day do
  runner "Recipe.setup_recipe_of_the_day"
end
```

ps: код лучше отрефакторить.